# Access rule in Yii issue

Tags: php, yii

When I log in, it sets the state:

**My code**:

```
 if (condition){
       Yii::app()->user->setState('isSuperAdmin', true);
    }else{
         Yii::app()->user->setState('isSuperAdmin', false);
    }
```

This is a custom controller, whose name is test, and has this function:

**Custom Controller:**

```
public function accessRules() {
        return array(
            array('allow',
                'actions' => array('index', 'delete'),
                'roles'=>array('Yii::app()->user->getState("isSuperAdmin")'),
            ),
            array('deny', // deny all users
                'users' => array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }
```

> Here it uses `accessRules()`. I want to check if the `isSuperAdmin` is set to
>   true, then I can access the controller test. Otherwise I don't have the role
>   to access.

How can I do that ?

Comment: There is a typo in isSuperadmin -> isSuperAdmin

Comment: @AndreyMischenko thx , but that is not the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [expression](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAccessRule#expression-detail) in your access rules:

```
public function accessRules() {
    return array(
        array('allow',
            'actions' => array('index', 'delete'),
            'expression'=>'Yii::app()->user->getState("isSuperAdmin")',
        ),
        ...
```

Comment: what is the difference between role and expression ? Why should I use expression instead of role ? I am a little confused and thx

Comment: Roles are usernames or user groups present by some text presentation like a '*', but expression is an an expression.

Comment: To add on to @KanchoIliev's comments, roles have to be defined in some sort of [role based access control structure](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#role-based-access-control), while expressions are just php statements that are evaluated using [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)